# Configuring Eclipse RCP Update manager

Tags: eclipse-rcp, p2

i finished my Eclipse RCP Application and wanted to configure the update manager. My Product is feature based and updates are working like they should, but i want to limit the user. i.e. force a special update site or display only grouped etc.

I tried using Policy but it does not work:

```
public class EPolicy extends Policy {
    public EPolicy() {
        setRepositoriesVisible(false);
        setGroupByCategory(false);
        setShowLatestVersionsOnly(false);
        setRestartPolicy(RESTART_POLICY_FORCE);
    }
}
```

registering in the Activator:

```
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    super.start(context);
    Policy policy = new EPolicy();
    context.registerService(Policy.class.getName(), policy, null);
}
```

am i missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set your policy with higher ranking,

```
public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
    super.start(context);
    Policy policy = new EPolicy();
    Dictionary props = new Hashtable();
    props.put(org.osgi.framework.Constants.SERVICE_RANKING, new Integer(99));
    context.registerService(Policy.class.getName(), policy, props);
}
```

Comment: that worked! thanks. 2 little things: it is Dictionary, not Directory, and the package name of Constants is org.osgi.framework.Constants